# Seeking Clarification on Server-Side Rendering (Next.js) Decision for DApp with Smart Contracts

Tags: server-side

Hello Ethereum community,

I've been working on a DApp that interacts with smart contracts, specifically a marketplace and an NFT contract. The DApp's current client-side rendering (CSR) approach led to slow loading times for NFT data. To enhance user experience, I introduced server-side rendering (SSR) using Next.js, resulting in noticeable performance improvements.

While I'm excited about the improved UX, I'm still looking to better understand the implications of using SSR in terms of server consumption and its potential impact on overall costs.

I came across a related question on Ethereum Stack Exchange (link: [should I use server side rendering(Next.js) for a dapp?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68457/should-i-use-server-side-renderingnext-js-for-a-dapp)), but the answers weren't entirely clear to me.

Could someone please provide more detailed insights into:

- How SSR impacts server consumption when interacting with Ethereum smart contracts?
- Strategies to measure and assess the increase in server usage after implementing SSR?
- Any real-world experiences or case studies demonstrating the trade-off between improved UX and potential higher server costs in DApps?

I greatly appreciate your expertise and guidance as I navigate this decision for my DApp.

Thank you!